# Difficulty setting up Eclipse

Tags: ros, ide, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to set up Eclipse to use as IDE for my ROS packages.
I decided to go with Eclipse above any other IDE because it's listed first in the ROSwiki.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs
I tried to follow steps 1-4 so far.
I'm afraid a few things went wrong tough:

PROBLEM 1:
ROSwiki Instructions step 4:
Properties --> C/C++ Make Project --> Environment, and check whether the following environment variables are assigned to the correct values:

## ROS_ROOT

## ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

## PYTHONPATH

## PATH

My issue: These variables were added, also in my case, but I dont understand their assign value:
for e.g. path the value the value is set to
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
which is also what i get if using "echo $PATH" ... is this correct? is this valid path? why to "mulitple" locations

PROBLEM 2:
If I have a look at the binaries in my packate (I use the "beginners_tutorial" package as described on the ROSwiki)
there is the "listener" and "talker" but they contain garbage like
ELF
�URHCF�*
���&�DMh()�

now if i expand the "talker" i also do find the "correct" code in a cpp file. But it seems something went wrong anyway if I have somethink like to above, no?

PROBLEM 3:
under "Problems" I get one warning
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/msg_gen/cpp/include).    beginner_tutorials-RelWithDebInfo@beginner_tutorials        pathentry   Path Entry Problem

PROBLEM 4:
I just cannot build the project, the build button is greyed out.

Really glad for any help with my problems.
Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10100/difficulty-setting-up-eclipse/) by [tschoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/618/tschoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2011-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem 1 is not a problem, it is normal. The path variable applies to all applications not just ROS so it points to the typical Linux directories.

Problem 2 doesn't seem like a problem either. Binary files are executable machine code. You aren't expected to look at them with a text editor. You would need a debugger or disassembler to make any sense of them.

3 - I assume the "Problems" heading you mention is actually "Console" window? Make sure the missing path actually exists then Go to Project/Properties and add the missing include path. It should have been included when you imported the project after doing the make project-eclipse, if your original version of the talker/listener was successfully compiling/running from the command line development steps in the tutorial.

Problem 4 is simple when you know how (but not when you don't). If the file has not been edited since the last successful compile, the Project/Build Project option is greyed out. Go to the source file, enter a single space somewhere and try again.

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-05-31**:
Thanks Gunther. "Problems" is a window I have never used. I will give it a try.

**Comment by [tschoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/618/tschoni/) on 2011-05-29**:
very very absolutely happy, first I was skeptical that so many "problems" show up, but turns out none of them very real ones :) it all works perfectly fine, thanks for the advice

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-29**:
Re problem #3: That warning can safely be ignored. (@Bart: it is actually the "Problems" view, not the "Console" view.) It stems from roslib incorrectly exporting msg_gen/cpp/include in its manifest.xml, but that dir doesn't exist. If you like, you can delete the path from Project/Properties.

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-05-29**:
p.s. - don't forget step 5 of the tutorial or your application won't run properly and start roscore first. I recommend getting familiar with the text editor/rosmake process as described in the simple tutorials first before trying Eclipse. Learn about the manfest.xml and CMakeLists.txt files first.